# Eclipse FP Cannot Get Documentation to Appear

Tags: eclipse, haskell, eclipse-fp

In the website [here](http://eclipsefp.github.io/features.html), it shows pictures of EclipseFP plugin with pop-up documentation.

[image: No documentation]

^ All I get is the type signature - "putChar :: Char -> IO()".

I have all the [helper executables](http://eclipsefp.github.io/install.html) other than the ones for web frameworks and SourceGraph and UUAGC. Sourcegraph not installing is [something else](https://github.com/ivan-m/SourceGraph/issues/3).

Anyway, I'm not getting pop up documentation for any of the standard library functions or my own user-defined functions. Also, I installed Hoogle...

[image: Hoogle]

and after installation I re-opened EclipseFP and it made no difference - no documentation for any function.

Comment: Repost here: https://sourceforge.net/p/eclipsefp/discussion/371922/thread/d0945a3c/

Answer (score 1):

I got it working!

[image]

After cabal installing every Helper executable (except for Web dev and SourceGraph) under "Window > Preferences > Haskell > Helper executables", I could get documentation on my own methods if they were written like this...

```
--
-- | Documentation appears in Haskell!!!
--
function signature
function
```

Note that if you try to write documentation like this, it doesn't render properly...

```
--
-- | Documentation
-- | a is the Int being returned
returnInt :: Int -> Int
returnInt(a) = a
```

^ Instead, it just prints "a is the Int being returned"

Comment: see https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/markup.html the pipe character should only be on the first comment line, not repeated.